# I want to automate general office admin tasks

Tags: python, automation, generic-programming, automator, office-automation

I want to automate general office admin tasks at work am looking into using Python as my programming language.  I am new to coding and understand basics but need guidance. I am proficient at using most me office programs and know sql but want to start automating tasks so that I can make time to further my coding skills. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am new to stack and new at forums as well so I'll be sure take the tips into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with Windows Office, then you will need to get started by downloading the pywin32 module. Pywin32 will allow you to interact with Office products. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32

If you need help installing, see this post [How to install pywin32 module in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863056/how-to-install-pywin32-module-in-windows-7)

How to get started, see here: [How do I get started with PyWin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545851/how-do-i-get-started-with-pywin32)

Comment: Thank you for the response and I will definitely look into the pywin32 and apiwin modules. I have already installed python 2.7 and have attempted to write code. I am stuck in trying to figure out which functions to use out of the many modules available. Do you have any resources for easy tutorials on how to discover and explore modules?

Comment: I would recommend something like the following resource to learn the basics https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python

Comment: @RaulLemus pywin32 is a great tool to work with Office products. Hope my solution helped. If so, please consider selecting it a correct. Thanks!